# get the session array value

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a session in a module and debug using watchdog in drupal 7

In module file I have created as

```
$_SESSION["celeType"] = $cele;
$_SESSION["count"] = $count;
watchdog('popup',print_r($_SESSION,TRUE));
```

In my dblog I got value as

```
Array ( [celeType] => Birthday [count] => 1 )
```

In my tpl I have printed as

```
echo $cele=$_SESSION["celeType"];
  echo $count=$_SESSION["count"];
```

This doesn't print any value.What I did wrong.

Comment: do you use `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: ya included in module file

Comment: dump value of $cele and $count before assign it and see if their content aren't empty

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $cele=$_SESSION["celeType"];
echo $count=$_SESSION["count"];
```

Shouldn't it be like this?:

```
echo $_SESSION['celeType'];
echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

Still, try doing

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

To check if the variables were set properly.

Comment: I think that echo $count=$_SESSION["count"]; is right because "The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned." as written in the php documentation. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: haven't seen people declaring variables inside an echo statement, it's weird and I'm not sure if that's right or not, but still worth it to try what I suggested, right? (: